# Perl data structure

Tags: perl, data-structures

I have a question regarding Perl data structures.

I have a file `1.txt` with the following fields and data.

```
Student rollno class
```

```
John,23,2
Mike,25,2
Ray,78,3
Tim,30,3
Mark,22,2
```

Can you please help how can print output in Perl?

I am splitting the file and getting an array but stumbling on the result set. Can you please describe how I can get the output as below?

```
2= john, mike, mark
3= ray, tim
```

I need a data structure which would combine that result set.

Comment: How have you tried to solve the problem so far?

Comment: It's very hard to help you to fix your program if you don't show your code. Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the 3rd column as the key for each, then you can set up a [Hash of Arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS) to manage the data.  First load in the file and split the fields by commas into an array.  Then setup the data structure as described in line 28 of the "Generation of a Hash of Arrays" example in the linked document.  Once you've got that all together, you just need to print it all back out, just like in the examples linked.

A quickie example of that strategy might look like this (note that I have the data in the `__DATA__` section of the script rather than reading from a file):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %results;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @elems = split(/,/, $_);
    push(@{$results{$elems[2]}}, $elems[0]);
}

for my $key ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %results )
    print "$key = ";
    print join(', ', @{$results{$key}}), "\n";
}

__DATA__
John,23,2
Mike,25,2
Ray,78,3
Tim,30,3
Mark,22,2
```

The output generated looks like this:

```
2 = John, Mike, Mark
3 = Ray, Tim
```

Comment: you probably want to sort the output:  `for my $key ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %results )`

Comment: Thank you. Correct  me if i am wrong but wont sorting will only rearrange the data. We want the kind of group by result set by class.

Comment: @ysth Yeah, that's a good point.  If it were my data, I would probably sort just as you suggested, just so we don't get a situation where '3' prints before '2' depending on how the hash is accessed.  I'll edit with that code improvement.